# How to open a terminal via intellij in the selected folder

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to right click on a file in intellij and open the terminal there in mac. I tried 'External Tools' but doesn't open the terminal in the selected directory even though I set $FileDir$ as the working directory of that tool

Comment: It is a good custom here at Stack Overflow to accept an answer (if you feel that your question has been answered) by clicking on the checkmark character - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . 
I noticed in your profile that you have almost never accepted any answer of your really many questions (65 questions, 50 answered, 3 accepted). 
Accepting is the way of saying "thanks" to people who gave their time and bothered with helping you with your questions and it is a gesture of politeness.

Answer (score 26):

#### 1. Out-of-the-box (no plugins)

Drag and drop a selected folder into the IntelliJ built-in Teminal opens a new terminal session in the *built-in Terminal*. (As @MariuszWróbel has written.)

#### 2. With plugins:

There are 2 plugins (as far as I know):

- [Open Terminal Here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/8081-open-terminal-here)
- [Open In Terminal](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7817-open-in-terminal)

[image]

Both the plugins open an *external terminal* (outside of IntelliJ). Each of them adds some item(s) to the context menu of files and folders:

[image]

#### 2a. [Open Terminal Here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/8081-open-terminal-here) plugin

It opens terminal in the current folder. The plugin works out of the box, no additional settings are required.

#### 2b. [Open In Terminal](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7817-open-in-terminal) plugin

It does the same as the previous plus offers opening the terminal in the root folder of the module. The plugin does *not* work out of the box, you need to configure it as described [here](https://github.com/luktom/OpenInTerminal).

[image]

> Linux:
>
> ```
> Terminal command: gnome-terminal
> Options: --working-directory
> ```
>
> Windows:
>
> ```
> Terminal command: cmd /C start cmd.exe /K
> Options: cd /D
> ```
>
> Windows (with babun or cygwin):
>
> ```
> Terminal command: C:<USER-DIRECTORY>.babun\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe
> Options: -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico C:<USER-DIRECTORY>.babun\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "cd \"$0\" ; exec bash"
> ```
>
> Mac OS:
>
> ```
> Terminal command: open -a Terminal
> ```

Answer (score 25):

You can just easily drag a selected folder and drop into terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Intellij, this seems to be integrated in the `Terminal` plugin, which is available by default.

You can either open a directory with your mouse by:

```
right click -> Open In -> Terminal
```

or assign a shortcut to the keymap command `Plugins/Terminal/Open in Terminal`.

Since creating a new terminal tab works with <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, I've assigned <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

just right click on the project folder that is being open in intelij, and select the option open in terminal